# htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Having a bit of trouble with htaccess, at the moment I have a rewrite rule that replaces the query string into a folder structure

```
RewriteRule profile/id/(.*) u_profile.php?id=$1
```

This spits out `/profile/id/1/` which is perfect, although, I'd really like to add another variable in there to also get the users name too.

At the moment I have a `$_SESSION['username'];` set for everyone who's logged in, I want to really pass it to the query string like so,

```
/profile/john/id/1/
/profile/sarah/id/1/
etc
```

Comment: It's not possible to pass PHP $_SESSION values to url rewrite, because url-rewriting executes before any PHP scripts. If you are using some framework, there could be workarounds for that. Please update your question with used framework, if any.

Comment: you can add cookie with username and then use it

Comment: Thanks for your kind assistance, answer below fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
RewriteRule profile/(.*)/id/(.*) u_profile.php?person=$1&id=$2
```

Then you can access the name through `$_GET['person']` and compare it to `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Kokos, what now if i wanted to remove the /id/ folder altogether for it to read, /profile/john/1/ ?

Comment: Very simple, change `profile/(.*)/id/(.*)` to `profile/(.*)/(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the id part, you just can remove `/id`

It would look like this:

```
RewriteRule profile/(.*)/(.*) u_profile.php?person=$1&id=$2
```